# Which is the PHP api to know if user facebook is an app fan or not -before the app authentication-?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I know there is this api to detect if an user is fan or not of an application

```
$facebook->api("me/likes/PAGE_ID");
```

but this function works only after you are authenticated.

I would like to know how could I get this information only when I reach my homepage applicatipn with me logged on facebook but not yet authenticated on the application.
is it possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: Part of the authentication process is allowing the application to access data about a user - this is part of that data. A user has to grant you permissions to access their "likes".

Comment: No, it's not possible.